# Calculating mean by group using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Here is my data:

```
x <- rnorm(0,1, n = 6)
class <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
df <- cbind(x, class)
```

I want to calculate the mean of x by class and have them repeat for all rows (I get a new column with the means for each class repeated so that the number of rows of the data frame remain the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
    group_by(class) %>%
    mutate(Mean = mean(x)) %>%
    ungroup
```

-ouptut

```
df
# A tibble: 6 x 3
        x class    Mean
    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1  2.43       1  1.05  
2  0.0625     1  1.05  
3  0.669      1  1.05  
4  0.195      2 -0.0550
5  0.285      2 -0.0550
6 -0.644      2 -0.0550
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(x, class)
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `ave`

```
transform(
    df,
    Mean = ave(x, class)
)
```